# Grafana Templating OpenTSDB

Tags: javascript, opentsdb, grafana

I'm having a problem with Grafana and OpenTSDB.

When I try to add a variable using the Grafana template feature with OpenTSDB as the data source and click execute query I get the following error message in the browser console:

```
TypeError: a.metricFindQuery is not a function
    at app.6e379bdb.js:20
    at i (app.6e379bdb.js:10)
    at app.6e379bdb.js:10
    at l.$get.l.$eval (app.6e379bdb.js:12)
    at l.$get.l.$digest (app.6e379bdb.js:12)
    at l.$get.l.$apply (app.6e379bdb.js:12)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (app.6e379bdb.js:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement._.event.dispatch (app.6e379bdb.js:6)
    at HTMLButtonElement._.event.add.q.handle (app.6e379bdb.js:5)
```

I'm very new to OpenTSDB and Grafana and I did not setup any of the system myself, so there may be a configuration problem that I'm not aware of here?

I've looked through the github issues for Grafana and it states that the feature to allow OpenTSDB to work with templating has been introduced and should be part of the main code base.

My aim is to create a template so that a user can select different graphs:

1.b.c

2.b.c

...

n.b.c

Where n is looked up from OpenTSDB. (I'm currently struggling with how I actually add the variable into a metrics query, something like: $n.b.c doesn't work but that is a separate issue to the error I'm getting)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Grafana version info:

Grafana version: 2.0.2, commit: v2.0.2, build date: 2015-04-22 16:51:50

I have also enabled: tsd.core.meta.enable_realtime_ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the OpenTSDB data source not supporting this feature in 2.0.2. It is supported in the very soon to be released 2.1 (this week)

you can download it already: 
http://grafana.org/download/builds.html

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for the information I will give 2.1 a try shortly. PS Thanks for Grafana, looking forward to using it a lot more.